# Extracting parameters to separate classes with interfaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, interface

I have this method in my service which is used for sorting, filtering and paging:

```
        public async Task<IPagedList<VehicleMake>> GetVehicleMakesWithPaginationAsync(string search, int? page, string sort)
    {
        var makes = _context.VehicleMakes.AsQueryable();

        switch (sort)
        {
            case "Name desc":
                makes = makes.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name);
                break;
            default:
                makes = makes.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
                break;
        }

        return await makes.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(search) || search == null).ToPagedListAsync(page ?? 1, 5);
    }
```

This method receives it's parameters from the controller action method:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string search, int? page, string sort)
    {
        ViewBag.SortNameParameter = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sort) ? "Name desc" : "";

        return View(await _vehicleMakeService.GetVehicleMakesWithPaginationAsync(search, page, sort));
    }
```

I was told that I should extract these parameters into separate classes with interfaces, for example like this:

```
public interface IFiltering
{
  string Search { get; set; }
}

public class Filtering: IFiltering
{
   public string Search { get; set; }
}
```

And then in my method make change from this:

```
Task<IPagedList<VehicleMake>> GetVehicleMakesWithPaginationAsync(string search, int? page, string sort)
```

to this:

```
Task<IPagedList<VehicleMake>> GetVehicleMakesWithPaginationAsync(IFiltering filtering, int? page, string sort)
```

I'm not sure how to do this. If I do this, I get an error in my controller action method "cannot convert from string to IFiltering". If I change parameter in controller action method to IFiltering also, i get an error "Cannot create an instance of an interface". Should I use dependency injection? In which way?

Comment: Can you post the code that is the start of the stacktraces of there errors?

Comment: [MissingMethodException: Cannot create an instance of an interface. Object type 'Project.Service.Data.IFiltering'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +233
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +531
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +330

Comment: That's ridiculous. I could conceive of someone arguing to encapsulate all three parameters into an interface so the method only takes one argument, but to make an Interface for strings and ints? I would listen to this person very critically.